Automation for Manage Zigbee device?
I have Tuya smart siren called Neo NAS-AB02. It is recognized by Zigbee in HomeAssistant and has ID TS0601 by _TZE204_t1blo2bj.
I bought it from Aliexpress, unfortunately when you buy it, you can not see the exact model. And my model does not have support to change volume and melody within HA.
However, it is possible, but manually. You go to device info page, and select Manage Zigbee Device, Clusters, select TuyaMCUSiren cluster and then you have the option to change the volume and melody through variables (for instance I can set variable melody to value 3, volume to 1, and so on.).
Now, this works very well, but it is manual procedure. Is it possible to create automation, for instance:
When “smart button number 1” is pressed:

set variable melody to value 3, volume to 1
ring two times
stop

When “smart button number 2” is pressed:

set variable melody to value 1, volume to 3
ring one time
stop

How to do that?
